# How to get whole element, innerHTML gets only inner part?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a function that gets the product and the id of this product, I need to put the entire HTML into local storage, I try it like this, but the innerHTML gets only the inner part, please tell me how to fix it?

```
function storagePlusQuantity(product, productId) {
    const storageId = 'product' + productId;
    localStorage.removeItem(storageId);
    localStorage.setItem(storageId, product);

    console.log(product)

}
```

The photo shows an example of the product of which I receive a function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIUW3.png)

Comment: Try `outerHTML`

Comment: So what is `product` exactly? You are missing the import part of the code that you retrieve the html. Side note: Seems very odd to store HTML and not data.

Comment: @epascarello This is a product from the basket, I'm trying to get it, increase its internal parameter by one, and sleep back. These products must copy to the second page of the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have code like this:

```
<div id="outer-div">
~~something~~
</div>
```

getting the `innerHTML` of the div will only get the `~~something~~` part.

What you want to do is just get the div with `outerHTML`.

See codepen example: [See Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/pankakes1/pen/PoRxQZq?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML returns the HTML code or text inside the selected element and outerHTML returns the elements whole code.

Let's see by examples

### innerHTML Example

```
<div id="container">Whoa!</div>
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
  console.log(x);
</script>
```

Output (In the console)

```
Whoa!
```

In the above code you can see JavaScript returns the code inside the selected element

### outerHTML Example

```
<div id="container">Whoa!</div>
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById('container').outerHTML;
  console.log(x);
</script>
```

Output (In the console)

```
<div id="container">Whoa!</div>
```

As you can see outerHTML returns all the elements code including tag, attributes and also the inner code
This Is The Difference Between InnerHTML and outerHTML.

Although outerHTML is rarely seen